# requestAnimationFrame: what exactly is the timestamp?

Tags: javascript

I have always thought that timestamp used by requestAnimationFrame is the same as usual timestamp in JavaScript, that is number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970. Today I have captured the timestamps to verify and found that the RAF timestamp are probably measured since the start of page loading. What precisely are the timestamps measured from?

The test code:

```
<p id="output"></p>

var i = 0;
var start = null;
var times = [];
var dur = 5000;

function step(timestamp) {
 if (start===null) start = timestamp;
 times[i++] = timestamp;
 if (timestamp-start<=dur) {
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
 } else {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = times.join('<br>');
 }
}

requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

gives results like this:

```
158.52126457412882
183.12243595205535
199.52116819316421
...
```

in all RAF capable browsers.

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame):  "The callback has one single argument, a [`DOMHighResTimeStamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp), which indicates the current time for when requestAnimationFrame starts to fire callbacks."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer in an article by Paul Irish and the specification of High Resolution time:

[requestAnimationFrame API: now with sub-millisecond precision](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/05/requestAnimationFrame-API-now-with-sub-millisecond-precision)

[High Resolution Time](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/HighResolutionTime/Overview.html)

The rAF time is "measured relative to the start of navigation of the document", that is relative to the "navigationStart attribute of the PerformanceTiming interface".

Answer (score 10):

It's a `DOMHighResTimeStamp` or a high-resolution timestamp (the same you get with `window.performance.now()`).

The time stamp is:

> current time for when requestAnimationFrame starts to fire callbacks.

The main difference between an ordinary timestamp and high-res timestamp is:

> DOMTimeStamp only has millisecond precision, but DOMHighResTimeStamp
>   has a minimal precision of ten microseconds.

Note: some browsers do not implement this aspect of rAF yet and may give you faulty or no value as argument.

Some resources:

- [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)
- [DOMHighResTimeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp)

Comment: "In the case of rAF it starts to count from when rAF is used. The first time stamp may be null." This not true. Try to add alert('paused') or so BEFORE the first call of RAF. The alert blocks script and if you click it about 5 s later, the first value in times array is about 5000...

Comment: @LeosOndra see update (I had more faulty implementations in mind - reworded)

Answer (score 0):

MDN says:

> The callback has one single argument, a DOMHighResTimeStamp, which
>   indicates the current time (the time returned from **performance.now()** )

And this is what **performance.now()** returns:

> The returned value represents the time elapsed since the **time origin**.
>
> The **time origin** is a standard time which is considered to be the
>   **beginning of the current document's lifetime**.

Comment: But, `requestAnimationFrame(t => console.log(t === performance.now()))` returns `false` in Chrome and FF.

Comment: @Odrin Because there is a time difference between your call to `performance.now()` and  internal call to `performance.now()` from `requestAnimationFrom()`. So it is supposed result of your's be **greater** than t, not equal.