# requestAnimationFrame inital timestamp

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

How do you get the inital timestamp for delta calculations in a requestAnimationFrame loop?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21316178/10226440) ive read that

> It's [requestAnimationFrame(**timestamp**)] a DOMHighResTimeStamp or a high-resolution timestamp (the same you get with window.performance.now())

thus I tried to do the following:

```
let lastTimestamp = performance.now()
const loop = (timestamp) => {
  console.log("exec at " + timestamp + " with delta " + (timestamp - lastTimestamp))

  lastTimestamp = timestamp
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}

requestAnimationFrame(loop)
```

But this gives negative values at the first frame **sometimes**. Which I really want to aviod since that might corrupt Animation logic. Id also like to not go with cheeky solutions inside the continuesly called loop (like `if (firstFrame) // do something differntly`) for performance reasons.

Comment: if (lastTimestamp==null) { console.log('first time') } else { console.log('not first time'); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the variable to null to start. First time it runs it will be null. Check for it.

```js
var loops = 0

let lastTimestamp = null
const loop = (timestamp) => {
  if (!lastTimestamp) {
    console.log("First Time!");
  } else {
    console.log("exec at " + timestamp + " with delta " + (timestamp - lastTimestamp))    
  }
  lastTimestamp = timestamp
  loops++
  if (loops<10) {  // just so demo is not runaway loop
    requestAnimationFrame(loop)
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(loop)
```

Comment: Well there would be no difference if it is the first time it is called.... So difference would be `0`

Comment: Yea I figured that you could simply skip the first frame and start executing afterwards...